# How to force Scrapy to scrape corresponding comments webpage after scraping article webpage?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl news articles and their comments with scrapy. In my case the news articles and their comments are on different web pages, as shown in the following example.

(1) Link for an article. 
http://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/editorials/if-britain-leaves-the-eu-will-scotland-leave-britain/article32480429/

(2) Link for the comments associated with the article. 
http://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/editorials/if-britain-leaves-the-eu-will-scotland-leave-britain/article32480429/comments/

I want my program to understand that (1) and (2) are related. Also, I want to make sure that (2) is scraped right after (1) rather than scraping other webpages in the middle. I use the following rules to scrape news article webpages and comments webpages.

```
rules = (
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = r'\/article\d+\/$'),   callback="parse_articles"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = r'\/article\d+\/comments\/$'), callback="parse_comments")
)
```

I tried to use explicit Request call in the parse function for articles as shown below:

```
comments_url = response.url + 'comments/'
print('comments url: ', comments_url)
return Request(comments_url, callback=self.parse_comments)
```

But it didn't work. How can I ask the crawler to scrape comments webpage right after scraping the article webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually set up a request to the comments page.
Every article page that your crawlspider discovers should have a comments page url somewhere, right?
In that case you can simply chain a review page request in your `parse_article()` method.

```
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = r'\/article\d+\/$'),   callback="parse_articles"),
    )
    comments_le = LinkExtractor(allow = r'\/article\d+\/comments\/$')

    def parse_article(self, response):
        item = dict()
        # fill up your item
        ...
        # find comments url
        comments_link  = comments_le.extract_links()[0].link
        if comments_link:
            # yield request and carry over your half-complete item there too
            yield Request(comments_link, self.parse_comments,
                          meta={'item':item})
        else:
            yield item 

    def parse_comments(self, response):
        # retrieve your half-complete item
        item = response.meta['item']
        # add some things to your item
        ...
        yield item
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's going to the appropriate comments link but it still doesn't scrape the comments page right after the article page. It scrapes other articles in between.

Comment: @user7009553 yes, because scrapy is asynchronous it scrapes multiple chains in parallel. So it might scrape article and schedule a request for comments while in the mean time scraping some other articles - your chains however will not lose order. Your chain in this case being parse_article->parse_comments->yield item, so you should be getting the results you expect.